# Minikube NGINX Ingress return 404 Not Found

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I created a deployment, a service and an Ingress to be able to access a NGINX webserver from my host, but I keep getting 404 Not Found. After a lot of hours troubleshooting, I'm getting to a point where some help would be very welcomed.

The steps and related yaml files are below.

**Enable Minikube NGINX Ingress controller**

minikube addons enable ingress

**Create NGINX web server deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver-white
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-webserver-white
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-webserver-white
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:alpine
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

**Create ClusterIP Service to manage the access to the pods**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webserver-white-svc
  labels:
    run: webserver-white-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-webserver-white
```

**Create Ingress to access service from outside the Cluster**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webserver-white-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: webserver-white-svc
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: white.example.com # This is pointing to the control plane IP
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: webserver-white-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

**Tests**

When connecting to one pod and executing `curl http://localhost`, it return the NGINX homepage html, so the pod looks good.

When creating a testing pod and executing `curl http://<service-cluster-ip>`, it return the NGINX homepage html, so the service looks good.

When connecting to the ingress nginx controller pod and executing `curl http://<service-cluster-ip>`, it also return the NGINX homepage html, so the connection between the ingress controller and the service looks good.

When connecting to the control plane with `minikube ssh` and executing `ping <nginx-controller-ip>` I see that it reaches the nginx controller.

I tested the same, but with a NodePort Service instead of ClusterIP and noticed that I could access the NGINX homepage using the node port, but not the Ingress port.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong and/or what else I could do to better troubleshoot this issue?

**Other notes**

- minikube version: v1.23.0
- kubectl version on the client and server: v1.22.1
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

The solution was to add the missing annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` on the Ingress.

Comment: How are you trying to access ingress ?

Comment: Two ways. With the command `curl http://white.example.com` on my host terminal or via browser on the address http://white.example.com.

Comment: The domain `white.example.com` has the same ip as `minikube ip` (control plane ip). I defined it on `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Could you confirm that by running: `kubectl get ingress` you have `HOSTS` and `ADDRESS` defined like in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource) example? Could you try to access using LoadBalancer IP?

Comment: This is the result for the ingress. NAME: webserver-white-ingress, CLASS: <none>, HOSTS: white.example.com, ADDRESS: , PORTS: 80. ADDRESS is empty.

Comment: I followed the example that you provided and on the `example-ingress` I also got ADDRESS empty even though the yaml file is the same. I also noticed that most people mentioned that the `ingress-nginx-controller` should be on the namespace `kube-system`, but in my case it is on the namespace `ingress-nginx`.

Comment: If I replace the service `type: ClusterIP` to `type: LoadBalancer` and also add `clusterIP: 10.103.199.250`, the service External IP will be `<pending>`. Then if I use `minikube tunnel`, the External IP is provided and I can access the NGINX homepage with `curl http://10.103.199.250`, but this still don't solve my issue which is to access the NGINX homepage through the Ingress. I'm wondering if this is a NGINX ingress bug. Soon I will test different versions to see if it works.

Comment: Just updated the post with the solution.

Comment: Great. @DanielSerrão, could you post this link with solution as the answer so it will be visible for the community?

Comment: I'm not sure what link you meant, but I just posted the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant just to ask you to post your solution as the answer, what you did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the missing annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" on the Ingress.